Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts"
github actions
google cloud artifact registry
Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts"
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.docker-helper) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')
Please run:
$ gcloud auth login
to obtain new credentials.
If you have already logged in with a different account, run:
$ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
to select an already authenticated account to use.
The push refers to repository [***/front-end]
2bb4a2be8519: Preparing
d26381110329: Preparing
e81429117070: Preparing
7bf3eb1a80e4: Preparing
43adef21ed65: Preparing
f7df5efb2c99: Preparing
5b316f9079a1: Preparing
5e19cd5b03d0: Preparing
678ea5c52c14: Preparing
8d853c8add5d: Preparing
f7df5efb2c99: Waiting
5b316f9079a1: Waiting
5e19cd5b03d0: Waiting
678ea5c52c14: Waiting
8d853c8add5d: Waiting
denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" on resource
i trying to create CD job with github actions and google cloud.
but i got a problem with permission.

Could you add more details / context to the question? Sharing the whole github action workflow config for example, for us to reproduce the error. As well as what you tried to resolve the issue until now. The error message seems straightforward regarding the token permission, I would check the credentials used in the process first.

you have to create a service account first
create a service account
then grant a new permisstion
enter image description here
principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/my-org/my-repo
enter image description here

great!
i actually missing principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/my-org/my-repo in the first step.
now it work perfectly.
thank you very much.
